# Datafactory Mapping Dataflow cannot format datetime to yyyy/MM/dd

Tags: azure, datetime, azure-data-factory

I am trying to convert date from '2019-12-12' to '2019/12/12' in my mapping dataflow.
But i cannot find dataflow expression which can convert to this format.

I want a function similar to formatDateTime() which is available in datafactory expression and not in dataflow expression.

Tried toDate()  ->doesnt take yyyy/MM/dd

Tried toTimestamp()   -> doesnt take yyyy/MM/dd

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you try adding another toString around the first one something like toString(toTimestamp(toString(byName('PostedTransactionDate')), 'yyyy-MM-dd') , 'yyyy/MM/dd') if I typed correctly.  If that works, depending on type of PostedTransactionDate you might be able to just do toString(byName('PostedTransactionDate'), 'yyyy/MM/dd') and avoid the conversions back and forth.

Comment: You want to convert '2019-12-12' to format 'yyyy/MM/dd', please tell us which is the 'MM', the first '12' or the last?

Comment: Hey @scott, ur first expression works well , but second didn't work for me. Thanks for the suggestion though:)

Comment: @chethan_raju put my solution as answer for you to accept.

Answer (score 2):

Your first conversion results in a timestamp which doesn't have a format.  To output with your desired format use the below which wraps your code with an additional toString() to format as desired.

```
toString(toTimestamp(toString(byName('PostedTransactionDate')), 'yyyy-MM-dd') , 'yyyy/MM/dd')
```

Answer (score 1):

You could using this expression:

```
toString(toDate('2019-12-12'), 'yyyy/MM/dd')
```

Result:
[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: Hey @Leon, i tried ur expression, it works when i explicitly give the date but doesnt work when i replace with a column name. 

toString(toDate(toString(byName('PostedTransactions'))),'yyyy/MM/dd')

Comment: @chethan_raju Why do you add '' to your column name? That's wrong. You could try `toString(toDate(PostedTransactions), 'yyyy/MM/dd')` or `toString(toDate(toString(byName(PostedTransactions))),'yyyy/MM/dd')`.

Comment: Hey @leon, i am using parameter in place of PostedTransactions since this changes for different tables. Since the parameter is of type string it should be inclosed in quotes.

Comment: @chethan_raju if you use 'PostedTransactions', expression won't get the values. It will be considered as a singe string. Can you you understand?

Comment: ,the byName() function seems to serve the purpose, i have tried using toString(byName('PostedTransactions')) and have got the row values and not the string.

Answer (score 1):

I used this approach to get a date column format, Used derived column and used this the expression.

```
 coalesce(toDate(YourDate,'MM/dd/yyyy'),toDate(YourDate,'yyyy/MM/dd'),toDate(YourDate,'dd/MM/yyyy'),toDate(YourDate,'MMddyyyy'),toDate(YourDate,'yyyyddMM'),toDate(YourDate,'MMddyyyy'),toDate(YourDate,'yyyyMMdd'))
```

I hope it works for you as well, Cheers

Comment: Is there any way to format 01-Jan-2021 00:00:23 to 01-01-2021?

Comment: you can play with the format expression to achieve your desired result